# Reduction to the special orthogonal group

Tags: vector-bundles, principal-bundles

It is well known that an $SL_n$-bundle $E$ on an algebraic curve $X$ is self dual (i.e $E\cong E^*$) iff it is an $SO_n$-bundle

However, I can't see why, because the isomorphism $E\cong E^*$ means that the transitions functions $g_{ij}$ verifies $$^tg^{-1}=a_igb_j$$
for some $a_i$ and $b_j$,

So, I want to see a proof.

Thanks.

Comment: That isn't what the first condition means. The first condition means that the transition functions can be taken to satisfy $\det g = 1$.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in fact I meant by it the assertion $E\cong E^*$, editiong